# Documentation examples with un-reviewed changes aren't syntax highlighted

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues, documentation

It looks like examples with a pending review doesn't syntax highlight code. I've looked at the source of the null-conditional index example and that doesn't appear to have any `<!-- lang:c# -->` (or similar, can't remember syntax) infront of it, so i'd expect the avoiding null reference exceptions one to have proper syntax highlighting without the `lang` tag.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.